# SDL draw image on screen using screen coordinates with multiple viewports

Tags: c++, image, mouse, viewport, sdl-2

I currently have two viewports in my game. One is for the information in the top (health, gold, magic, etc) and the other viewport shows the map area. I created my own custom mouse cursor using an image and I'm displaying that image just like any other and update the position based on my mouse cursor position. My only problem is that I can only draw that image on a viewport. I have it set the show up on the map area, and when I move my mouse to the top; it won't display on the information area. It just leaves the window. So the first thing I did (I knew it wouldn't work, but tested it anyways) was to draw the mouse on both viewports. But that shows two mouse cursors when moving to the top of the screen (LOL). My question is how can I get the mouse image to draw on the screen using screen (or window) coordinates, outside of the viewport. Does that make sense? I want to be able to move the mouse anywhere on the screen so I can click on items in the map viewport as well as the information viewport.

My viewport class is very simple:

Viewport.h

```
#pragma once

#include <SDL.h>

class Viewport
{
public:
    Viewport(int x, int y, int width, int height);
    ~Viewport();

    SDL_Rect GetViewport();

private:
    SDL_Rect viewport;
};
```

Viewport.cpp

```
#include "Viewport.h"

Viewport::Viewport(int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
    viewport.x = x;
    viewport.y = y;
    viewport.w = width;
    viewport.h = height;
}

Viewport::~Viewport()
{

}

SDL_Rect Viewport::GetViewport()
{
    return viewport;
}
```

In my Game class I initialize two variables for each Viewport

```
Viewport hud;
Viewport arena;
```

In the constructor I initialize them to the appropriate sizes. Then In my game drawing function I set the viewports accordingly and draw in the appropriate viewport.

```
// gfx is my Graphics class. Everything that has to do with drawing is inside that class; including setting the viewport for the render.
gfx.SetViewport(hud.GetViewport());
// This is where I would draw stuff on the hud viewport

gfx.SetViewport(arena.GetViewport());
// Where I draw the map, enemies, etc.
```

my SetViewport function is setup like this:

```
void Graphics::SetViewport(SDL_Rect viewport)
{
    SDL_RenderSetViewport(renderer, &viewport);
}
```

How can I get my mouse image to be drawn (with the viewport not relavant).  Below are some images of what I'm talking about.

Only displaying on the arena and won't show on the hud.
[image]

Displays the mouse on both if I draw the mouse on both viewports
[image]

**Edit: I made a workaround which will work for this game**
*I'm just worried that it won't be good for performance on a bigger and larger game*

I created another viewport that is as large as the screen (window) and I'm drawing the mouse to that viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Super late answer but here it is. Calling SDL_RenderSetViewport(renderer, NULL) will reset the viewport to the entire window.

You should do this before you call SDL_PollEvent as well because if you poll mouse events when a viewport is active the mouse motion event coordinates will be relative to the viewport and not the main window.